# Can I use a Plotly graph in Bokeh?

Tags: python, plotly, bokeh, holoviews

bokeh does not have a Sankey graph and the Sankey graph available in holoviews is not as good as the one Plotly. Is there a way to embed the plotly graph into a bokeh dashboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Panel](https://panel.pyviz.org) makes it simple to embed Plotly, Matplotlib, Altair, and many other types of plot into a Bokeh-based dashboard, so that you can pull in whatever you need from any plotting library. That said, it would be helpful to file an issue with [holoviews](https://github.com/pyviz/holoviews/issues) to outline the features you wish were in the HoloViews Sankey implementation, because it's easier to get a consistent look and feel if you use plots from the same library.

Comment: I cannot find an example in Panel on how to embed a plotly graph. Could you point me to the right documentation or possibly a snippet code example would be really appreciated

Answer (score -1):

It is documented [here](https://panel.holoviz.org/reference/panes/Plotly.html).
Just add your resultant figure to the panel `pn.pane.Plotly(fig)` . Here is my example

```
import plotly.express as px
pn.extension("plotly")
data = pd.read_csv("species.csv")
var= ['home_species', 'planted_species']
fig = px.treemap(data, path=[i for i in var], values='density')
ss=pn.pane.Plotly(fig)
pn.Row(ss).servable()
```